# Variance in Recurring Events

Tags: recurring-events

I have a recurring event, i.e. at 9:00 every Sunday.
If I change one of these future events to be at 10:00 instead of 9:00, then what would you call this event? a "time-varied event" perhaps?

Comment: How about the much simpler *rescheduled*?

Comment: An exception to the normal recurring time.

Comment: The title of your question seems to describe it well: a variance in a recurring event. Beyond that, you will need to explain what kind of answer you're looking for—and why you are rejecting some descriptions.